# System.getenv() used in spring boot is shown as a security vulnerability in sonarQube

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables

I have method in my spring boot application which takes the data from system environment variable, the method works as intended but sonarQube says "Make sure that environment variables are used safely here",
I tried to find an alternative to fix this issue but I am unable to find a solution, here is the method:

How can I handle this security issue, I cannot use anything other than getting the values from environment variables.

```
public Map<String, Object> getConfigurations() {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
         String xVaultToken = System.getenv("XVaultToken");
         String cityAppConfig = System.getenv("CityApp_Config");

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
                .setSslcontext(
                        new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, (x509Certificates, s) -> true).build())
                .build();
        Map<String, Object> headerDatas = new HashMap<>();
        headerDatas.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headerDatas.put("X-Vault-Token", xVaultToken);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(cityAppConfig);
        Set<String> keys = headerDatas.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            get.setHeader(key, headerDatas.get(key).toString());
        }
        response = client.execute(get);
        try(BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()))){
            String responseData = rd.readLine();
            result.put(Constants.RESPONSE, responseData);
        }
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        result.put(Constants.STATUS, statusCode);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("error is local settings getConfigurations" + e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Does the Sonnar suggests some alternatives?

Comment: You don't need to find alternatives, just "Make sure that environment variables are used safely here" as the sonar qube message says. Have you read the sonar documentation on why this is considered a vulnerability and how to proceed?

Comment: @JoãoZarate No it doesn't provide any alternatives, it just says "Make sure that environment variables are used safely here"

Comment: @pafauk. I did and my concern here is not about the security but to resolve with an alternative which I am unable to find sir.

Comment: You can keep the information in an external file ... in the SO directory system ... and load it from this file.

Comment: Isn't this about [sanitizing this like any other input](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Security%20Hotspot/RSPEC-5304)? If OP sqays they're stuck with env variables, I guess that's case for talking to whoever thought storing the token as env var was a good idea and a possible //NOSONAR

Comment: Why not let Spring Boot handle this. If this class is managed by Spring, you can either inject the `Environment` and do a `getProperty` or just use `@Value("${XVaultToken}"` on an instance field. Added benefit you could now also move this config to the `application.properties` or whatever means Spring Boot supports (the System Environment is one of those).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Disclaimer !!!

First of all, as I mentioned in my comments, if someone requires you to read an ENV-Variable but also says that you can't mark the SonarQube warning as false-positive: Tell them (politely) that they'll have to live with that SonarQube warning.

However, if that is for any reason not an option, I will show you 2 ways that may not trigger the warning in SonarQube which are still much less verbose than calling `cmd.exe` for that purpose.

## Example 1

### Call the function via `java.util.function.Function`

```java
private static String getenv(String variable) {
    return ((Function<String, String>) System::getenv).apply(variable);
}
```

## Example 2

### Call the function via reflection

```java
    private static String getenv(String variable) {
        try {
            return (String) System.class.getMethod("getenv", String.class).invoke(null, variable);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works for me! (I understand that i need make changes because Sonar is helping me, but this give me time and that is so good)

Answer (score 4):

All these "security hotspot" warnings are just "TODO" notifications and should be solved in three steps:

1. Make sure that the value is really used securely.

   - In this particular case: you are invoking GET request to externally-supplied URL and then use the value from response. What happens when someone changes the environment variable value by some clandestine means and point it to their own web server? Is the response used for anything sensitive? Sometimes even the fact that the URL is invoked can be used for nefarious purposes (tracking). etc etc
2. Add `@SuppressWarnings({"squid:S5304"})` annotation, with proper description in a comment.
3. Make sure that everything is properly reviewed, **including** the reasoning from step 1. Remember: Two heads are better than one (especially in security).

Answer (score 0):

Its LOW-level issue can be suppressed using `@SuppressWarnings({"squid:S5304"})`.
Add this statement on class level.

Answer (score -1):

After searching a lot I figured using environment variables to store important information is a bad idea, but if you no other option like me, here is the workaround:

Instead of using System.getenv("XVaultToken"), use a method like this

```
private String cmdUrl = "cmd.exe /c echo %wfManagement_Config%";
String cityAppConfig =  getEnvironmentVariable(cmdUrl)

private String getEnvironmentVariable(String cmd){
    String environmentVar = "";
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor(); 
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
         p.getInputStream())); 
        String line; 
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
            environmentVar = line;
        }
        return environmentVar;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Exception-->"+e);
    }
    return environmentVar;
    
}
```

The method runs a command and fetches the environment variable for you, for some reasons sonarQube ignores this and doesn't give a security issue.

Comment: SonarQube tries to help you. You should not build Code-Workarounds just so SonarQube doesnt trigger a warning for you. If you say you really need that env variable at that point and you're sure about what you're doing: Mark it as false positive. But don't build code workarounds just so SonarQube doesn't trigger! This is a very bad idea!

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying, but I wasn't allowed to make it a false positive and they weren't budging on not using env variables, so I had to find a workaround.

Comment: Then I would tell them that THEY have to live with a security warning. Also, you could just call the `getenv` method via Reflection and SonarQube would not trigger. Ugly, but not as ugly as spawning an external process to do it, which also only works on one platform (windows)

Comment: So actually making code that doesn't clearly express what it is doing, and by making it hard to run it is ok.